# Understanding the term "open position"

Tags: financial-literacy, terminology

The investopedia page on [open position](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/open-position.asp) states that:

> The recommendation for investors is to limit risk by only holding open positions that equate to 2% or less of their total portfolio value

I am new to financial markets and trying to learn how they work; what I don't understand about this statement is: if investors should only hold open positions of 2% of total portfolio value, and an open position includes a long position (i.e. holding stock) then where is the rest of the 98% of the value held?!

I realise I must be missing something so blatantly obvious/ intrinsic it's proving hard for me to google this question, hence the q. here.

Comment: The author should replace "open positions" with "each open position".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your link:

> For example, holding a 2% portfolio position in stocks spread out through multiple sectors—such as financials, information technology, health care, utilities, and consumer staples along with fixed-income assets such as government bonds—represents a diversified portfolio.

Suppose your portfolio is worth $100k.  2% of $100k is $2k.  Therefore, no single existing position should be larger in value then $2k, regardless of the security type.

Comment: Do index funds count as a single open position, or many?

Comment: Any security that you own would be a single open position (stock, option, ETF, mutual fund, bond, futures, etc.).  If adhering to such a rule, one would want to look for large overlap.  Two identical but different ETFs on the same index would mean a 4% exposure in that sector.  I wouldn't get all worked up over a 2% stock position in XYZ and a 2% position in an ETF that contains XYZ.  And if one was concerned about this, one could reduce the 2% position in XYZ to account for the thinner slice of exposure to XYZ in the ETF.